# Как остановить функцию JS с помощью mouseout?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть функция makeItRain, которая создаёт эффект дождя на странице при её вызове. Есть две кнопки в виде ссылок, на которые при наведении должна вызываться функция makeItRain, а при отведении заканчивается. При наведении никаких проблем не возникло, но makeItRain после отведения мыши от кнопок не останавливается. Для этих целей я использовал mouseover и mouseout, также пробовал использовать setInterval.

```js
let makeItRain = function () {
  $(".rain").empty();

    let increment = 0;
    let drops = "";
    let backDrops = "";

  while (increment < 100) {
    let randoHundo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (98 - 1 + 1) + 1);
    let randoFiver = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 2 + 1) + 2);
    increment += randoFiver;
    drops +=
      '<div class="drop" style="left: ' +
      increment +
      "%; bottom: " +
      (randoFiver + randoFiver - 1 + 100) +
      "%; animation-delay: 0." +
      randoHundo +
      "s; animation-duration: 0.5" +
      randoHundo +
      's;"><div class="stem" style="animation-delay: 0.' +
      randoHundo +
      "s; animation-duration: 0.5" +
      randoHundo +
      's;"></div><div class="splat" style="animation-delay: 0.' +
      randoHundo +
      "s; animation-duration: 0.5" +
      randoHundo +
      's;"></div></div>';
    backDrops +=
      '<div class="drop" style="right: ' +
      increment +
      "%; bottom: " +
      (randoFiver + randoFiver - 1 + 100) +
      "%; animation-delay: 0." +
      randoHundo +
      "s; animation-duration: 0.5" +
      randoHundo +
      's;"><div class="stem" style="animation-delay: 0.' +
      randoHundo +
      "s; animation-duration: 0.5" +
      randoHundo +
      's;"></div><div class="splat" style="animation-delay: 0.' +
      randoHundo +
      "s; animation-duration: 0.5" +
      randoHundo +
      's;"></div></div>';
  }

  $(".rain.front-row").append(drops);
  $(".rain.back-row").append(backDrops);
};

document.addEventListener("mouseover", startInterval);
document.addEventListener("mouseout", stopInterval);
let timer = null;

function startInterval() {
    timer = setInterval(document.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
        if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a' ||
            event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'p') {
            makeItRain();
        }
    }, 1000));
}

function stopInterval() {
    document.addEventListener("mouseout", (event) => {
        if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a' ||
            event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'p' ) {
            /* Здесь я пытался разными способами остановить функцию makeItRain */
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<body class="back-row-toggle splat-toggle">
    <div class="rain front-row"></div>
    <div class="rain back-row"></div>
    <div class="toggles"> 
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>BEST</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="btns">
            <a id="first" href=""> 
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <p>Some<br>Thing</p> 
            </a> 
            <a id="second" href=""> 
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <p>Some</p> 
            </a>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <script src="west.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: setInterval(document.addEventListener("mouseover".... Каждую секунду навешивает плюсом еще один слушатель mouseover.. Зачем?

Comment: Да, моя ошибка. Всё теперь исправлено. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код для запуска дождя по наведению и остановке по отведению мыши

```js
var makeItRain = function(off) {
if(off) return $('.rain').empty();
 
var increment = 0;
var drops = "";
var backDrops = "";
 
while (increment < 100) {
var randoHundo = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (98 - 1 + 1) + 1));
var randoFiver = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 2 + 1) + 2));
increment += randoFiver;

drops += '<div class="drop" style="left: ' + increment + '%; bottom: ' + (randoFiver + randoFiver - 1 + 100) + '%; animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.2' + randoHundo + 's;"><div class="stem" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.2' + randoHundo + 's;"></div><div class="splat" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.2' + randoHundo + 's;"></div></div>';

backDrops += '<div class="drop" style="right: ' + increment + '%; bottom: ' + (randoFiver + randoFiver - 1 + 100) + '%; animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"><div class="stem" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div><div class="splat" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div></div>';
}
 
$('.rain.front-row').append(drops);
$('.rain.back-row').append(backDrops);
}

let el = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
  el[i].addEventListener('mouseover',()=>{ makeItRain(); });
  el[i].addEventListener('mouseout',()=>{ makeItRain(1); });
}
```

```css
body{
  background:black;
}
.container{
position:relative;
color: white;
z-index:999;
}
.btns{
  width: fit-content; 
}
/*Стили выше добавил*/

.rain {
margin-top: -180px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 2;
}
 
.rain.back-row {
display: none;
z-index: 1;
bottom: 60px;
opacity: 0.5;
}
 
.back-row-toggle .rain.back-row {
display: block;
}
 
.drop {
position: absolute;
bottom: 100%;
width: 15px;
height: 120px;
pointer-events: none;
animation: drop 0.5s linear infinite;
}
 
@keyframes drop {
0% {
transform: translateY(0vh);
}
75% {
transform: translateY(90vh);
}
100% {
transform: translateY(90vh);
}
}
 
.stem {
width: 1px;
height: 60%;
margin-left: 7px;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25));
animation: stem 0.5s linear infinite;
}
 
@keyframes stem {
0% {
opacity: 1;
}
65% {
opacity: 1;
}
75% {
opacity: 0;
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
}
}
 
.splat {
width: 15px;
height: 10px;
border-top: 2px dotted rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
border-radius: 50%;
opacity: 1;
transform: scale(0);
animation: splat 0.5s linear infinite;
display: none;
}
 
.splat-toggle .splat {
display: block;
}
 
@keyframes splat {
0% {
opacity: 1;
transform: scale(0);
}
80% {
opacity: 1;
transform: scale(0);
}
90% {
opacity: 0.5;
transform: scale(1);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
transform: scale(1.5);
}
}
 
.toggles {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 3;
}
 
.toggle {
position: absolute;
left: 20px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
line-height: 51px;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-align: center;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
border-radius: 50%;
cursor: pointer;
transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
 
.toggle:hover {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
 
.toggle:active {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
 
.toggle.active {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
 
.splat-toggle {
top: 20px;
}
 
.back-row-toggle {
top: 90px;
line-height: 12px;
padding-top: 14px;
}
 
.single-toggle {
top: 160px;
}
 
.single-toggle .drop {
display: none;
}
 
.single-toggle .drop:nth-child(10) {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="toggles"> 
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>BEST</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="btns">
            <a id="first" href=""> 
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <p>Some<br>Thing</p> 
            </a> 
            <a id="second" href=""> 
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <p>Some</p> 
            </a>
            <a id="next" href=""> 
                <p>Some</p> 
            </a>
        </div> 
    </div>
<div class="back-row-toggle splat-toggle">
<div class="rain front-row"></div>
<div class="rain back-row"></div>
</div>    
</body>
```

Решил переписать без jQuery т.к. считаю не оправданным подключать библиотеку исключительно из-за этой анимации.

```js
var makeItRain = function(off) {
if(off) {
  document.querySelector('.rain.front-row').innerHTML="";
  document.querySelector('.rain.back-row').innerHTML="";
  return
}
 
var increment = 0;
var drops = "";
var backDrops = "";
 
while (increment < 100) {
var randoHundo = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (98 - 1 + 1) + 1));
var randoFiver = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 2 + 1) + 2));
increment += randoFiver;

drops += '<div class="drop" style="left: ' + increment + '%; bottom: ' + (randoFiver + randoFiver - 1 + 100) + '%; animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.2' + randoHundo + 's;"><div class="stem" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.2' + randoHundo + 's;"></div><div class="splat" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.2' + randoHundo + 's;"></div></div>';

backDrops += '<div class="drop" style="right: ' + increment + '%; bottom: ' + (randoFiver + randoFiver - 1 + 100) + '%; animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"><div class="stem" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div><div class="splat" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div></div>';
}
 
document.querySelector('.rain.front-row').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",drops);
document.querySelector('.rain.back-row').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",backDrops);
}

let el = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
  el[i].addEventListener('mouseover',()=>{ makeItRain() });
  el[i].addEventListener('mouseout',()=>{ makeItRain(1) });
}
```

```css
body{
      background:black;
    }
    .container{
    position:relative;
    color: white;
    z-index:999;
    }
    .btns{
      width: fit-content; 
    }
    /*Стили выше добавил*/

    .rain {
    margin-top: -180px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    }
     
    .rain.back-row {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 60px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    }
     
    .back-row-toggle .rain.back-row {
    display: block;
    }
     
    .drop {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 120px;
    pointer-events: none;
    animation: drop 0.5s linear infinite;
    }
     
    @keyframes drop {
    0% {
    transform: translateY(0vh);
    }
    75% {
    transform: translateY(90vh);
    }
    100% {
    transform: translateY(90vh);
    }
    }
     
    .stem {
    width: 1px;
    height: 60%;
    margin-left: 7px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25));
    animation: stem 0.5s linear infinite;
    }
     
    @keyframes stem {
    0% {
    opacity: 1;
    }
    65% {
    opacity: 1;
    }
    75% {
    opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
    opacity: 0;
    }
    }
     
    .splat {
    width: 15px;
    height: 10px;
    border-top: 2px dotted rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0);
    animation: splat 0.5s linear infinite;
    display: none;
    }
     
    .splat-toggle .splat {
    display: block;
    }
     
    @keyframes splat {
    0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0);
    }
    80% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0);
    }
    90% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.5);
    }
    }
     
    .toggles {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    }
     
    .toggle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 51px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
    }
     
    .toggle:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    }
     
    .toggle:active {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    }
     
    .toggle.active {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    }
     
    .splat-toggle {
    top: 20px;
    }
     
    .back-row-toggle {
    top: 90px;
    line-height: 12px;
    padding-top: 14px;
    }
     
    .single-toggle {
    top: 160px;
    }
     
    .single-toggle .drop {
    display: none;
    }
     
    .single-toggle .drop:nth-child(10) {
    display: block;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="toggles"> 
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <header>
                <h1>BEST</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="btns">
                <a id="first" href=""> 
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <p>Some<br>Thing</p> 
                </a> 
                <a id="second" href=""> 
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <p>Some</p> 
                </a>
                <a id="next" href=""> 
                    <p>Some</p> 
                </a>
            </div> 
        </div>
    <div class="back-row-toggle splat-toggle">
    <div class="rain front-row"></div>
    <div class="rain back-row"></div>
    </div>    
    </body>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё идеально работает.

Comment: На здоровье! :)